# Can I use a downloaded GTA V on another PSN account?

Tags: ps3, psn

If you download GTA 5 from PS-Store and have to change PSN account. Is it possible to still have GTA 5 even though you've changed account?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way that you can transfer games or savegames between different PSN accounts. Sources [[1]](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Vita-Support/Moving-a-game-from-one-account-to-another/td-p/42179779), [[2]](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Network-Support/How-do-I-transfer-purchases-to-new-PSN/td-p/44341128).

However, if the same account is still on the same PS3, then you can still play the game (from source 2):

> If you have two accounts on the same PS3/PS4 then all accounts should be able to take advantage of the games & the PS Plus subscription though.

Comment: I find this answer a bit misleading, probably because the question wasn't so clear to me, because the second part shows that what the asker tries to do would indeed work (changing PSN account on a PS3 and still playing the game with the other account). But maybe I misunderstood the question. You can also transfer saves to other accounts as far as I know, as long as they're not copy-protected. Since GTA 5 has an online component though I assume they are protected so in this case it wouldn't work, but I think it's not impossible in general.